# Problem with block matching in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video-processing

I have written matlab codes for two different block matching algorithms, extensive search and three step search, but i am not sure how i can check whether i am getting the correct results. Is there any standard way to check these or any standard code which i can run and compare my result with.I read somewhere that JM software can be used but i didnt find any way to use it.

Comment: Based on the lack of answers, I think you may need to edit your question and add some more detail so we can better understand the problem and help you.

Comment: +1 for "you may need to edit your question"

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the results produced by your algorithms to create the next frame of video and then analyze its quality by either visually inspecting it (which is rather subjective, and we like to deal in numbers) or calculating the mean square error between the produced image and the one you're trying to estimate. Mean square error of the exhaustive (extensive) search should be lower than the one three-step gives you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, did you try to plot it? I mean,after the block-matching you have a new image, right?.

A way to know if you result if true or not is to check the sum of the difference of 2 frames.
A - pre_frame
B - post_frame
C - Compensated frame

If abs(abs(A-B)) is lower than abs(abs(A-C))) that mean it could be true.

Next time, try to specify your algoritm.  Also, put your code here to help you more.